# Can't change permissions on /snap/inkscape/4019 directory. chmod: changing permissions of '4019/': Read only Filesystem

Tags: chmod, inkscape

I am trying to edit the `scour.inkscape.py` file in the `/snap/inkscape/4019/share/inkscape/extensions` directory. The permissions for this file is set to `-rwxr-xr-x`. Problem is linux won't let me make any changes in the `/snap/inkscape/4019` directory. I can make any changes outside this directory though. This is what the inkscape directory looks like:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 276 Mar 11 18:05 4019
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   4 Jul 23 01:06 current -> 4019
```

When I try to change permissions on the 4019 dir with `sudo chmod 777 4019`, chmod throws a error:

> chmod: changing permissions of '4019/': Read-only file system.

Pretty much all posts that I read about the issue told to remount the filesystem or reboot, but the 4019 directory is not a filesystem, it is a directory and rebooting didn't work. I'm running Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

This won't fix snap, but it **will** solve your problem:

1. Uninstall the snap package of Inkscape:

   ```
   sudo snap remove inkscape
   ```
2. Install the official Ubuntu package from Inkscape's ppa at https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install inkscape
   ```